# scheduling Mi ZigBee smart plug without internet connection

Tags: zigbee, xiaomi

I have bought a xiaomi ZigBee smart plug and paired it with my Mi hub. I want the plug to control my router. But when I set on/off schedules , it will turn off the router but it wont turn it on after the scheduled time. Can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cant be done  Via Gateway V2 as far as i know.I used the gateway V3 and scheduled it via mihome app . it set the network mode of automation to lan mode for some automations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).